# Getting my class to work in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class

I have created C# classes before in non-web application projects. Normally, All you have to do is add a class file to the project and you can add an instance on the forms, no namespacing or using required. But I noticed in ASP.NET, when you create a class and try to create a instance, i'm getting errors saying the directive or assembly reference missing. I don't understand why? Okay, so most likely I have to take the hard way, and create a class library and use namespacing or add a reference yet STILL the same errors. I'm confused here why I can't seem to get this simple empty class working.

I currently have a class called Class1.cs in my App_code folder. I have an web form called About.aspx.

my class called Class1.cs

```
 using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
using VideoWebsite;

   namespace VideoWebsite1
  {
       public class Class1
    {

    public Class1()
    {
    }
    public string tag { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

my web form About.aspx

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Web.Configuration;
 using VideoWebsite1;


  public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           Class1 p = new Class1();
           lbltag.text =(string) p.Tag;
      }
  }
```

update: Changing Build Action to compile to my class file fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Class1` is inside same project then yes you can refer it directly like the way you are intending to do but if you have created the class in a different project then include/add that project reference in your web project referenced dll list.

Then most probably the `Build Action` of the class is not set to `compile`. To check the same do below

Right click on the `Class1.cs` file under `App_Code` folder and check its `Build Action` property. If not set then set it accordingly.

Comment: The class1.cs in my App_Code folder in the same project, Sorry for the typo with the using statement. yea one is videowebsite and videowebsite1, doesn't seem to help even if both are videowebsite1 or videowebsite.

Comment: "Then most probably the Build Action of the class is not set to compile. To check the same do below". That fixed it Rahul. You are a great computer wizard. Thank you, sir.

Comment: .cs files have build action set to compile by default. I take that you've done some extra tinkering  there.

Comment: Actually I did not tinker with it, it seem to have been set as default.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
using VideoWebsite;
```

The compiler can't locate it so it's asking for a new reference to an assembly containing that namespace.

If that is a typo and you actually meant VideoWebsite1, you can remove it all together, since that is also the namespace of Class1.

Comment: don't look like that's issue, see `about.aspx` code part

Comment: They differ. One has a trailing '1'.

Comment: `class1` defined under namespace `VideoWebsite1` and in web form he is using the correct namespace. *using VideoWebsite1;*

Comment: @Rahul Yes, but in Class1 he references a VideoWebsite namespace. Without the trailing '1'.

Comment: @Rahul Did you spot it?

Comment: yea that's a mistake, even if i titled them both using videowebsite1 or videowebsite, i still get the same errors.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Class1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  This is the error I'm getting. This is the error you normally get when it can't find the class file or I didn't place the using statement correctly.